# HTML button has to be pressed twice to get the table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my HTML:

```html
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="" enctype="">
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br>
                        MySQL
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        User <br>
                        <input type="text" name="user" id="user" required>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Password <br>
                        <input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" required>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Database <br>
                        <input type="text" name="db" id="db" required>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" id="goBtn">Go</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And this is the jquery and Ajax call:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#form1").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // const user = $("#user").val();
        // const pwd = $("#pwd").val();
        // const db = $("#db").val();

        console.log("MESSSADRFE")
        var text = document.getElementById("showDatabaseTableForm");
                if (text.style.display === "none"){
                    text.style.display = "block";
                } else{
                    text.style.display = "none";
                }
        var login = {
            user: $("#user").val(),
            pwd: $("#pwd").val(),
            db: $("#db").val()
        }

        $.ajax({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/qbe/?query={login(user:"'+$("#user").val()+ '",pwd:"'+
        $("#pwd").val()+ '",db:"'+$("#db").val()+ '"){table}}',
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
        }, 
        
        type:'POST',
        data: login,
        success: function(result){
            data = result.data.login;        
            var htmlCode = "<table><tr>";
            arr = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var item = Object.values(data[i]);
                //arr.push(item);
                console.log(item);
                
                 htmlCode+= '<td><b>'+item+":"+'</b></td>'
                     htmlCode +='<td><select id="dropdwn">'+
                    '<option value="0">0</option>'; 
                    
                    for (var j = 1; j<  3; j++){
                        htmlCode+='<option id="first" value="'+item+'">'+j+'</option>';
                        
                        console.log(j);
                    }

                    //htmlCode += '</td>';
            }
            htmlCode += "</select></td></tr><table>";
            htmlCode +='<input type="button" value="Get Skeletons" onclick="getInfo()"><input type="reset" value="Reset Skeletons">'
            $("#showDatabaseTableForm").html(htmlCode);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("ERROR");
            console.log(console.error);
        }
    });
    });
});
```

The first time I click on the button 'Go', nothing happens, the second time, it displays the result. Can help someone help me fix the jquery code? I want to be able to click the button once.
Thank you

Comment: i think it's mostly because your button type is submit change it to button and change your jquery from "$("#form1").on('submit', function(e)" to $("#goBtn").click(function()

Comment: I tried it, same conclusion

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but what is the purpose of this?

```
if (text.style.display === "none") {
    text.style.display = "block";
} else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Feels like the first time you click the button you hide the element, then the second time around, as the display is "none", you show it.

Comment: When I press Go, the table I am trying to display should suddenly appear.

Comment: Could you also share the HTML where `showDatabaseTableForm` is and corresponding stylesheet?

Comment: <form class="showForm" id="showDatabaseTableForm">

            
        </form>
The table should be placed in the form. When I press Go, it should display a table. That table has its own functionality, its own button. I am getting data from the database through an API

Comment: Is that form element hidden or do you just have the tags like that? It's empty, it wouldn't show anything. But this doesn't mean that its style.display is "hidden". When you first click the button, if this is the only code you have and no stylesheets associated that are hiding it, then you are proactively setting style.display to "none", which hides it even though it has content. Can you try removing that block of code? I don't think you need it here.